# Using Beautiful Soup for HTML tables that lack </td> tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling with parsing some flaky HTML tables down to lists with Beautiful Soup.  The tables in question lack a </td> tag.

Using the following code (not the real tables I'm parsing, but functionally similar):

```
import bs4
test = "<table> <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr> <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr> </table>"
def walk_table2(text):
    "Take an HTML table and spit out a list of lists (of entries in a row)."
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
    return [[x for x in row.findAll('td')] for row in soup.findAll('tr')]

print walk_table2(test)
```

Gives me:

```
[[<td>1<td>2<td>3</td></td></td>, <td>2<td>3</td></td>, <td>3</td>], [<td>4<td>5<td>6</td></td></td>, <td>5<td>6</td></td>, <td>6</td>]]
```

Rather than the expected:

```
[[<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>], [<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>]]
```

It seems that the lxml parser that Beautiful Soup is using decides to add the </td> tag before the next instance of </tr> rather than the next instance of <td>.

At this point, I'm wondering if there a good option to make the parser place the ending td tags in the correct location, or if it would be easier to use a regular expression to place them manually before tossing the string into BeautifulSoup...  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Beautiful Soup's behavior seems perfectly rational.  It finds the `</tr>' tag and concludes any open tag inside the table row needs to be closed.  Although it's perfectly rational, it's also probably wrong.

Comment: I don't know about what Beautiful Soup does, but by HTML 5's rules, the parser should be in '"in cell" insertion mode' which specifies to close the first td before opening the new one. In HTML 4, under SGML parsing rules, `TD` has an optional closing tag and cannot contain nested `TD` so should be closed when encountering a new opening tag: `<!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->` - so this behavior is objectively wrong by either standard and cannot be called 'perfectly rational': This code is legal HTML and is unambiguously a properly structured table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing decisions made by Python's built-in HTML parser. If you don't like the way that parser does things, you can [tell Beautiful Soup to use a different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). The html5lib parser and the lxml parser both give the result you want:

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(test, "lxml")
>>> [[x for x in row.findAll('td')] for row in soup.findAll('tr')]
[[<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>], [<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>]]

>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(test, "html5lib")
>>> [[x for x in row.findAll('td')] for row in soup.findAll('tr')]
[[<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>], [<td>1</td>, <td>2</td>, <td>3</td>]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a BeautifulSoup bug to me.  I found [this page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/3.1-problems.html) detailing why there are regressions in BS 3.1 from 3.0.8 (including "'bad end tag' errors") which suggest that, for parsing bad HTML, one option would be to jump back several versions.  That said, the page says it's been superseded and now exists only for historical reference.  It's unclear however exactly how much BS4 resolves the issues introduced in BS 3.1 - at the very least, it couldn't hurt to try the older version.

Answer (score 1):

A patchy fix to get you through this particular pinch:

Massage the incoming data with a regex (this is VERY brittle, and I know how stackoverflow feels about regexes and html but C'MON, just this one time...)

```
import re
r1 = re.compile('(?<!\<tr\>)\<td', re.IGNORECASE)
r2 = re.compile('\<\/tr>', re.IGNORECASE)
test = "<table> <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr> <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr> </table>"
test = r1.sub('</td><td', test)
test = r2.sub('</td></tr>', test)
print test
```

Oh, and `test` afterwards:

```
<table> <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr> <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr> </table>
```